# Cronjob with python logging script

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to figure out how to run a `python` script with a `cronjob`. Here is my simple script:

```
import logging
import pathlib
import os


from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S")

    path = pathlib.Path.cwd()
    log_dir = pathlib.Path.joinpath(path, 'tmp_logs2')

    log_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    log_file = timestamp + '.txt'

    with open(pathlib.Path.joinpath(log_dir, log_file), 'w') as f:
        f.write("Hello world! %s" % timestamp)
```

And this is the crontab (I would like the script to log the time every two minutes) command I'm running (I execute it with `crontab -e`):

```
*/2 * * * * python3 my_script.py
```

However, it seems the logging is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what output do you get?  most cron systems will email you the standard output/error stream.  I'm assuming there will be details of an exception which would explain what's going on

Comment: @SamMason That's the thing - there is no output. There are no errors, and nothing is being logged anywhere.

Comment: what have you checked for output?  https://linuxhint.com/check-cron-logs-linux/ or https://superuser.com/q/122246/171763